# writing old date with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.14 to create an excel file, that must contains differents types of datas, including dates.

My code works fine in most of the cases.
I'm facing problems when writing specifics dates (java.util.Date) in cells.
Here is my code :

```
 Date date;

 // code where I get the value of date

 Cell currentCell = currentRow.createCell(fieldPos++);

 // line below doesn't work for date like '11/11/1811' but work for '11/11/2111'
 currentCell.setCellValue(date);

 currentCell.setCellStyle(myDateStyle);
```

Let's suppose I have 3 dates to write:

- 01/01/2009
- 11/11/2111
- 11/11/1811

My excel file will look like that:

| 01/01/2009    | 11/11/2111 |    *blankcell*    |

The line currentCell.setCellValue(date) sets the value to -1 when date is equal to 11/11/1811 so in my excel file it appears blank ( according to my dateStyle)

Why it is not working for specific date and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the cause of this !

setCellValue(Date d) of Apache Poi try to convert a given java.util.Date into an excel "datenumber" :

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.

That's why when given a date before 1900 setCellValue sets the value to -1 cause it can't make the convert operation.

Fixed my problem with calling setCellValue(String s) with the Date.toString() in case of setCellValue(Date d) sets -1 , the only remaining problem is that I alterate the data.