# Apache Poi results in #### for date

Tags: java, apache-poi, date-formatting

I am using Apache Poi and trying to format dates in Excel. My code looks like this:

```
public void addItem(Date item, int columnNum, Row currentRow) {
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat(YYYY-MM-DD));
    
    Sheet currentSheet = workbook.getSheet(currentSheetSiteName);
    
    Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(columnNum);
    cell.setCellValue(item);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
.
.
.
```

My code works fine for most dates but not for "younger" years: when I want to write the date "0001.01.01" the cell only shows "#######". Can anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Writing the date as a String is not a solution for me.

Comment: I think, excel has problems/needs workaround for pre-1900 dates...https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/pre-1900-dates/m-p/129999, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/calculate-age-before-1-1-1900 , poi-specific: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37182669/592355 , https://user.poi.apache.narkive.com/RXe4yo0Z/generating-excel-file-with-dates-prior-to-1900

Answer (score 0):

This may be your cell width is not enough to display the date, so the date will be displayed as ####.
Please try to arrange your cell width long enough.